# using posix read with a limited buffer size

Tags: c, file, file-io, posix

I am writing a application in which I would have to parse the contents of a file.  I am using some library functions that do not play nice with a dynamically allocated array.  This force me to have a fixed sized array on stack.  Parsing data however, will not work if a line is only partially read and I am forced to use POSIX read to achieve this.

```
char buff[512] = '\0';
int fileHandle = open( scEndOfLinePPSPath , O_RDONLY );

if(-1 != fileHandle)
{
    while( 0 < read(fileHandle, &buff, sizeof(buff) - 1) )
    {
        parse(&buff); /* doesn't play nice with dynamically allocated memory */
```

The second I start trying to limit the buffer size, I could encounter cases in which parse would fail since the file is bigger and a line would only be partially read (so the parse algo has only partial data to work with).

If the read buffer ends like illustrated below the parse algorithm obviously cannot get the attribute name and the next read would being with the second half of the attribute name:

<Node> attribute="Mai

Is there a elegant way to handle such cases while continuing to use just POSIX read?  I know I could dynamically allocate memory based on file size, but as I said, dynamically allocated memory doesn't work well with the parse library.

Thanks!

SOLVED:

Thanks for your inputs everyone!  The problem is solved now.  I am able to use dynamic memory allocation and create buffers big enough for the entire file.

I was determining the file size using lseek.  Somehow, the read API reads 3 bytes more than the size reported by lseek or fstat, so the allocated buffer wasn't big enough for successful parsing.  Does this mean, lseek is not a reliable way to determine the file size?

Comment: Please define "doesn't play nice with dynamically allocated memory." That doesn't really make sense, unless it does some really weird stuff.

Comment: How can it be that `parse()` works with fixed-size arrays but not with dynamically-allocated ones?  It shouldn't be able to tell the difference, unless it's assuming buffers of a specific size.

Comment: What will you do if the input file happens to contain a line longer than `sizeof(buff) - 1` ?

Comment: If the parse function used sizeof() for example, the result would be different for a dynamically allocated buffer and a local array. When I use a dynamic array the parse function ends up in a segmentation fault.  The parse function is the qnx ppsparse api!

Comment: @Ashwin If `sizeof` is used on the buffer from inside the parse function, the size it returns will depend on the type in the parameter list and not on the buffer that was passed to the function... and arrays in the argument list are treated as the pointers they decay to... so `sizeof` should return the size of the pointer, whether the buffer was dynamically allocated or not.

Comment: [The documentation](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_pps%2Fapi%2Fppsparse.html) says that `ppsparse()` requires the buffer to be zero-terminated.  A segmentation fault is a likely result of passing it a buffer that is not zero-terminated, regardless of whether the buffer was dynamically allocated.  My answer already explains what you must do.

Comment: The array was zero terminated.  But the issue was with the way the read API was behaving.  I was allocating the buffer based on the return value of lseek,  but read API reads 3 more bytes!  Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you generally don't know how long the lines that you are going to read are -- you need to read them first and look for newlines, at which point you've probably read part of the next line as well, so you need to make sure you don't lose it.  So you end up needing code that loops reading into a buffer while also looking for newlines and moving data after the newlines earlier in the buffer.

So you usually end up with something like:

```
char buffer[512];
char *data_start = buffer, *data_end = buffer;

while(1) {
    if (char *eol = memchr(data_start, '\n', data_end-data_start)) {
        /* have a full line, null-terminate and pass to parse */
        *eol = '\0';
        parse(data_start);
        data_start = eol+1;
    } else {
        /* no newline in the buffer -- read more */
        if (data_start != buffer) {
            /* move leftover data (if any) to the front of the buffer */
            memmove(buffer, data_start, data_end - data_start);
            data_end -= data_start-buffer;
            data_start = buffer; }
        if (data_end == buffer + sizeof(buffer)) {
            /* line too long for the buffer -- can't deal with it */
            break; }
        int rv = read(fd, data_end, buffer+sizeof(buffer)-data_end);
        if (rv <= 0) {
            /* error or end of file */
            break; }
        data_end += rv; } }
```

You can avoid the "line too long" problem by using a dynamic buffer that you grow (probably double in size) when the buffer is full and there's no newline in it.

Comment: Have a look at the `getline()` function as well, it takes care of making the buffer large enough.

Answer (score 0):

The `parse()` function should not be able to distinguish a buffer that is dynamically allocated from one that is declared as a fixed-size array.  It might, however, expect the buffer to have a specific size.  In that case, it is the `parse()` function's problem to handle data that cross a buffer boundary (presumably requiring multiple calls), but it is *your* problem to ensure that the buffer is the expected size and is completely filled before each call (except at end-of-file, which must be signaled to `parse()` in some way).  The `read()` function does not guarantee to do that, which could be your issue.

If you want to read all available bytes into your buffer, up to its capacity, then you need to be prepared to perform multiple `read()`s.  It looks something like this:

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 512

char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
ssize_t next_offset = 0;

do {
    ssize_t n_read = read(fd, buff + next_offset, BUFF_SIZE - next_offset);

    if (n_read == 0) {
        /* end of file */
        buff[next_offset] = 0;  /* add a terminator */
        break;
    } else if (n_read < 0) {
        /* handle error ... */
    } else {
        next_offset += n_read;
    }
} while (next_offset < BUFF_SIZE);
```

Alternatively, the problem may simply be that `parse()` expects a (zero-terminated) C string.  If you declare the buffer statically and initialize any part of it, then the elements not explicitly initialized will be automatically initialized with '\0'.  If the buffer happens to be larger than your input, then that gets you a terminator semi-automatically, but if your input happens to be the size of your buffer or longer then you are hosed.  With a dynamically-allocated buffer, on the other hand, you need to leave space for the terminator, and you need to insert it at the end manually.  (And you still need to be prepared to perform multiple `read()` calls, as described above).